# How to do calculation plus and minus with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm still new using Javascript I have some problem with calculation using javascript right now. 
The problem is it won't count.

Let me know which one I made mistake and how to solve it.
I'm really sorry because this is my first time using javascript.

```
<script text="javascript">
    var p = 0;
    var b = 0;
    var c = 0;
    function calc() {
      var p = document.getElementById("pokok").value;
      var b = document.getElementById('bonus').value;
      var c = document.getElementById('cut').value;

        if (p == 'pokok') { }
        total = p + b - c;

        document.getElementById("total").value=total;
    }
</script>
```

What I want to do from my code is

P + B - C = total

so basically 
10 + 10 - 5 = 15

Answer (score 2):

A few points:

1. `document.getElementById(<string id>).value` returns a `string`. Using `+` on two `string` objects performs a concatenation of the two.
2. You've forgotten to close your function declaration with a `}`.
3. You've arbitrarily declared `p`, `b`, and `c` in two completely separate contexts.
4. You have an `if` statement `if (p == "pokok") {}` that doesn't actually do anything.

(Since you haven't included your relevant HTML, I've taken the liberty of creating some for demonstration purposes.)

The solution specific to your question is to parse the `input`s' values as integers using [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) before attempting to add them:

```js
function calc() {
  var p = parseInt(document.getElementById("pokok").value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('bonus').value);
  var c = parseInt(document.getElementById('cut').value);

  total = p + b - c;

  document.getElementById("total").value = total;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="pokok" placeholder="pokok" />
<input type="text" id="bonus" placeholder="bonus" />
<input type="text" id="cut" placeholder="cut" />
<button onclick="calc()">Calculate</button>

<input type="text" id="total" placeholder="total" disabled="disabled" />
```

Comment: Hello, 
Thanks a lot for the solution. 
I really appreciate it for you to help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use '+' before each value to cast string to number

```
function calc() {
  total.value = +pokok.value + +bonus.value - +cut.value
}
```

```js
function calc() {
  total.value = +pokok.value + +bonus.value - +cut.value
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="pokok" placeholder="pokok" />
<input type="text" id="bonus" placeholder="bonus" />
<input type="text" id="cut" placeholder="cut" />
<button onclick="calc()">Calculate</button>

<input type="text" id="total" placeholder="total" disabled="disabled" />
```